How to install a recent version of graphviz usable with RHEL 8?
I want to install a recent version of graphviz (e.g. Graphviz version 12) on a RHEL 7 system.
When I look at RPMfind I can only see rpms for Fedora. Where do i find a RPM for RHEL 7?

In other words if you check this exhaustive list of official sources, there's no official RPM for modern graphviz on old RHEL. You will have to build that package yourself, or work on a more modern release of RHEL, or need to work in a container.

and, this addresses exactly that situation: I need a package for my version of RHEL/EPEL/CentOS/Fedora, but it's only packaged for other versions of Redhatoids

@MarcusMüller That's probably the best answer. Makes total sense. Will try to build Graphviz myself on that machine.

in the latest RHEL-8.10 as of this date, it is graphviz-2.40.1-39.el8.x86_64 and it comes from the rhel-8-for-x86_64-appstream-rpms repository.

@ron version 2.40 is way too old. There are some significant Unicode bugs in there which are fixed in version 10.0.1 - Building from source was the way to go!

@MarcusMüller got me with his comment to the right approach: Building Graphviz myself.
I couldn't use version 12 as I wished for (because it requires  C++ 17 features which RHEL 7 does not provide with its default repos), but Graphviz version 10 (which is still reasonably recent) I was able to install.
